# How to merge object inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array

```
  var input = [["group1","group2","group3" ], ["group1", "group5" ]]
```

I would like to merge two objects like this :

```
  ["group1","group2","group3", "group1", "group5" ]
```

I tried to merge two objects in one array, however, I couldn't get the answer.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, you don't: you want to concatenate arrays, not merge objects. To concatenate arrays, there is the built in [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function.

Comment: This is called "flattening".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with js, but can't you concat two arrays with something like

```
var merged = input[0].concat(input[1]);
```

Comment: This should work beautifully. Good answer.

Comment: It works ! thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `concat()` like so:

```js
const input = [
  ["group1", "group2", "group3"],
  ["group1", "group5"]
];

const output = [].concat.apply([], input);

console.log(output);
```

Or alternatively, `Array.prototype.flat()`:

```js
const input = [
  ["group1", "group2", "group3"],
  ["group1", "group5"]
];

const output = input.flat(1);

console.log(output);
```

Or if that is "hard" data, and will not change, you could use an even simpler `concat()` operation:

```js
const input = [
  ["group1", "group2", "group3"],
  ["group1", "group5"]
];

const output = input[0].concat(input[1]);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the concat function to combine the arrays.

```
const resultArr = [];

input.forEach(curr => {
  resultArr.concat(curr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about 'flattening the array'...

```
const flatten = (array) => {
  return array.reduce((flat, toFlatten) => {
    return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatten(toFlatten) : toFlatten);
  }, []);
}
console.log(flatten([[1,2,[3]],4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

ES5

```
array.reduce(function(a, x) { return a.concat(x); }, []);
```

ES6

```
array.reduce((a, x) => a.concat(x), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple approaches that you could take, my favorite would be to use the reduce method to transform your bi-dimensional array into one flat array and it would look like this :

```
function reducer(final_flat_array, inputItem) {
    return [...final_flat_array, ...inputItem]
};
let flat_array = input.reduce(reducer, []);
```

or a more 'imperative' way I guess :

```
let flat_array = [];
input.forEach(item => flat_array.push(item);
```